# Custom Clone of specific fields only using the standard form in VF

Tags: custom, clone

Is there a way to clone specific fields and save only when the save button is click?

Only five fields should be cloned, assign new value to one field and the rest of the fields are empty.

below is sample of my controller.

```
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
    private SampleObject__c RecordQueried{get;set;}
    public SampleObject__c Record {get;set;}

    public AD_PartialClone_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        this.controller = controller;
        Record = (SampleObject__c)controller.getRecord();
        SampleObject__c cloned= new SampleObject__c();
        RecordQueried = [select Id,
                              Column1__c,
                              Column2__c,
                              Column3__c
                       from SampleObject
                       where id =: Record.Id]; 

        cloned.Column1__c = RecordQueried.Column1__c;
        cloned.Column2__c= RecordQueried.Column2__c;
        cloned.Column3__c = RecordQueried.Column3__c;
        cloned.Column4__c = 'COMPLETED';


        RecordQueried = cloned;
    }

    public PageReference cloneOffer() {

         Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
         SampleObject__c  OfferCloned;
         try {
             OfferCloned = RecordQueried.clone(false,true);
             insert OfferCloned;
         } catch (Exception e){
            Database.rollback(sp);
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
         }
        return new PageReference('/'+OfferCloned.id +'/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F'+OfferCloned.id);

    }
```

**VF page**

Comment: You would have to build a lightning:component for it.

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal, Is it possible to use or override the standard form? I see some blogs but it directly save the record even you cancel the form.

Comment: Not in lightning, but you can follow what @Jayant suggested in Apex.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

Based on your latest information, and as understood, you are clicking a custom Clone button on a VF page and that you need to clone specific fields only. This understanding is not same as understood earlier with your initial version of the question which seemed like you wanted to use a standard Clone button in LEX, if that was the case, the earlier answer is the approach to do so.

In your current scenario with VF, you need to utilize the logic that you have in your controller's constructor and **not use *clone()* method** as you are doing in your method. This implementation should be straight forward as:

1. On clicking of the custom clone button, create the new target object and load your form
2. Now in Save method, populate the specific fields only as you have fetched in the constructor. By only setting these values, you let all other fields as null (note: if you have any validation rules on fields not populated, you still need to populate such fields)
3. Save your record only when you call the Save button, in that method you just insert the target object and redirect it to the newly created record
4. If someone now clicks the custom Cancel you have in here, you are never saving the record because its only saved in the step above

---

The short answer to your question is **Yes**. I had been in almost similar situation which we were able to address as explained below. You can utilize the very same approach to selectively clone fields.

You will need to handle this in your trigger. Unfortunately an API which could have helped here was *isClone() & getCloneSourceId()*, but that does not work in LEX. There's a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCRCQA2&title=isclone-and-getclonesourceid-apis-not-working-for-contact-in-lightning) for this. But this is how you can do it following way:

1. Create a custom field say *Source Id* on your object
2. Populate this field in *after insert* of every record, with the record Id of the record that was just created
3. Now when you want to Clone a record, in your *before insert*, you will check if the *Source Id* field is populated or not. If it is populated, that will necessarily mean that this record is part of a Cloning process instead of being created net New (because remember this field is always populated after insert trigger)
4. Once you identify the flow based on the *Source Id* field, New vs. Clone, you can then specify which selective fields you want to clone vs. which ones to ignore.

With this approach, you don't need to create any custom components but utilize the standard out of the box Clone button with combination of some trigger logic.