# isClone( ) doesn't work for cloning from UI

Tags: cpq, steelbrick

Once i am cloning the quote line on QuoteLineEditor page(please find the attached screenshot of cloned icon of quitelineeditor page) of CPQ Steelbrick, I am trying check in apex if the new line is cloned and also to get the parent record cloned id using isClone() and getCloneSourceId(). But in unfortunately its value is coming false nad null respectedly. I have also seen this post: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DDVvIAO where it has been mentioned that "isClone() func does not work for cloning from UI". So can anyone please help me how to identify a new Quote line reocrd was cloned from UI(QuoteLineEditor Page) in apex.[image]

Comment: You may have been impacted with [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCRCQA2&title=isclone-and-getclonesourceid-apis-not-working-for-contact-in-lightning)

Comment: Yes I have seen that post previously itself. So is there any way I can get this done. Or I can get any workaround ?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217830/54851), that should help.